# I am receiving the "Invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var cols = [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20];

  if(sh.getName() != "TF Attendance" || cols.index0frange.columnStart) = -1) 
    return;

  e.range.offset(0,1)
      .setvalue((typeof e.value = 'object') 
                 ? null
                 : new Data())
 }
```

This code was working, I added 4 more columns

Comment: `=` is assignment. You want comparison which is `==` or `===`. (Next time please tag the question with the programming language you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't just add more columns:

```
if( sh.getName() !="TF Attendance" || cols.index0frange.columnStart) = -1)
                                                                     ^---
```

you also deleted an `=`, so your `or` condition is now trying to do an assigment to something that cannot be assigned to. `==` is an equality test, `=` is the assignment operator.

And in logical terms the code makes no sense anyways. You're testing a boolean result against `-1`. booleans cannot be negative. they're only ever true/false, or 0/1. never negative.